# How can I set file permissions for all users from Haskell

Tags: linux, haskell, file-io

I am trying to achieve the same as `sudo chmod 755 myfile` would.

I found `getPermissions` and `setPermissions` in [System.Directory](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/directory-1.0.1.1/System-Directory.html#v%3asetPermissions), but that only allows me to set permissions for the current user (in my case root).

Do equivalent functions exist that apply to all users or is the only viable option to use a `rawSystem` call, which I consider a bit unclean?

Comment: `rawSystem` would certainly be unclean.  Part of the issue here is you are confusing a program that you execute from a shell (`chmod`) with a primitive function that you hope corrosponds with some underlying system call (or perhaps a libc operation resulting in several system calls).  If you want to execute some primitive system operation then look at making an FFI call.  In this case (if it weren't already implemented by someone else, as ehird points out) you would want FFI bindings to [chmod or fchmod](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`System.Posix.Files`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-Files.html) in the standard unix package has POSIX files permission support. The reason `System.Directory` doesn't offer such functionality is for portability.